# Determine which estimator is best

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, parameter-estimation, mean-square-error

> Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_{100}$ be observations from a $X_i \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ for $i =1,...,100$, where $\lambda > 0 $ is an unknown parameter. The following estimates for $\lambda$ are given by:
>   $$
> \widehat{\Theta}_{50} = \frac{1}{50}(X_1+X_2+...+X_{50})
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> \widehat{\Theta}_{100} = \frac{1}{100}(X_1+X_2+...+X_{100})
> $$
>   Determine which estimate is best by using mathematical notation.

First I have just written that more observations are better in general but I have also found the MSE for both estimates:

$$
\begin{split}
MSE &= E[(\widehat{\Theta}-\theta)^2] \\
    &= \operatorname{Var}(\,\overline{\!X}-\theta)+(E[\widehat{\Theta}-\theta])^2 \\
    &= \operatorname{Var}(\,\overline{\!X}) \\
    &= \frac{1}{n^2} \operatorname{Var}(X_i) \\
    &= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}(x) \\
    &= \frac{\lambda}{n}
\end{split}
$$
Thus resulting in $MSE(\widehat{\Theta}_{50}) = \frac{\lambda}{50} > MSE(\widehat{\Theta}_{100}) = \frac{\lambda}{100}$ whereby I would conclude that the smaller MSE the better and would argue that 50 observartions < 100 observations.

Am I missing any argumentation? This is an earlier exam question from my course which I am studying for.

Thanks.

Comment: Yep... you showed that more data is better.  (Who could ever think otherwise?)

Comment: Oh, yes, I did mean that. Would my answer be sufficient for maximum points?

Comment: The sample variance, as you have shown, is $\frac\lambda n$. Obviously this is decreasing with $n$. So yes, your answer is correct.